# How to store efficiently all text edits?

Tags: php, string, text, data-structures, database-design

I'm building PHP Symfony 4 + Vue.js app. And one of it's part — text editor, which remembers all edits in text. I saw how the same problem solved in ACE editor — they save every letter, but I don't need such precision. It will be enough to store substrings with type of action. Something like:

```
{ action: add, from: 0, to: null, text: "New string" }
```

And result text will be: "New string". Then I changed something:

```
{ action: add, from: 3, to: 4, text: 'Delicious S' }
```

And result became: "New Delicious String". Storing such "commits" with text, I can reconstruct state of text in a some moment, beeing applied published commits until required moment.

Do I think correct or are there some better way?

Maybe you know some efficient algorithm or data structure to store such task?

What edit coordinates in text should I use, to work with them more efficiently?

Comment: Smart idea, however is the complexity really worth it? Storage is abundant and cheap.

Comment: Lots of texts can have lots of edits... so, store full text after every text edit, I think, will be expensive. Maybe not from storage cost, but from network loading and server RAM load, when we will be sending to user history of text edits. Also, we need to have possibility to highlight edits, more of it to have possibility to highlight all edits by one user.

Comment: I heard about Event Oriented Databases. But never worked with it. Maybe, have you some advices about them?